# Type Mismatch: Can't convert double into double[]

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call, type-mismatch

When i am running this java code i got error. I am new to java. Can anyone help.

```
package raza.project.arrays;
import java.util.*;
public class arraysLearning {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [] numbers = { 25,36,38,63,89,52,74};
  double[] med = median(numbers);
}
  //Return the median value of an array of numbers
//without changing the parameter array
public static double median(int[] numbers) {
 int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
 Arrays.sort(tmp);
 int mid = tmp.length/2; // Note: int division
 if (tmp.length%2 == 0) { // even length?
 return (tmp[mid-1]+tmp[mid])/2.0; //float division
 }
  else {
     return tmp[mid];
     }
  }
}
```

**java compiler is latest jdk14**

Comment: `median(numbers)` returns a double. You're trying to assign the result to `double[] med`, which is an array.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method: `public static double median(int[] numbers)` returns an object of type `double`.

When you want to call a method a get the result in a variable, you need to make sure the variable is of the same type as the type returned by the method.

You need to change this line:

```
double[] med = median(numbers);
```

With

```
double med = median(numbers);
```

Here, the variable is of type `double` and the method returns a `double`. Both types matches, the compiler is happy and your code compiles. But in your case, the type is `double[]` and the method returns a `double` object... There is no match, so your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Your median() method is supposed to return a "double" value and not an array of double values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] numbers = {25,36,38,63,89,52,74};
  double med = median(numbers); // remove [] on this line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a double value but you are returning it to a double array, there is type mismatch.

import java.util.*;
public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numbers = { 25,36,38,63,89,52,74};
    double med = median(numbers);
}
//Return the median value of an array of numbers
//without changing the parameter array
public static double median(int[] numbers) {
    int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(numbers, numbers.length);
    Arrays.sort(tmp);
    int mid = tmp.length/2; // Note: int division
    if (tmp.length%2 == 0) { // even length?
        return (tmp[mid-1]+tmp[mid])/2.0; //float division
    }
    else {
        return tmp[mid];
    }
}
```

}